# Using functors in CUDA

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have the following class functor in CUDA

```
class forSecondMax{
private:
    int toExclude;
public:
    __device__ void setToExclude(int val){
        toExclude = val;
    }
    __device__ bool operator () 
       (const DereferencedIteratorTuple& lhs, const DereferencedIteratorTuple& rhs) 
  {
    using thrust::get;
    //if you do <=, returns last occurence of largest element. < returns first
    if (get<0>(lhs)== get<2>(lhs) /*&& get<0>(rhs) == get<2>(rhs)*/ && get<0>(lhs) != toExclude/* && get<0>(rhs)!= toExclude */) return get<1>(lhs) < get<1>(rhs); else
    return true ;
  }

};
```

is there a way to set the value of toExclude from the host?

Comment: Why don't you define a constructor? That would be the canonical way of setting data member during object instantiation, which happens on the host when using a thust functor....

Comment: @talonmies: Can you please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006148/function-object-not-working-properly#comment19343809_14006148

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to solve achieve this is to define a constructor for the functor which sets the data member from an argument. So your class would look something like this:

```
class forSecondMax{
    private:
        int toExclude;
    public:
        __device__ __host__ forSecondMax(int x) : toExclude(x) {};
        __device__ __host__ bool operator () 
            (const DereferencedIteratorTuple& lhs, 
             const DereferencedIteratorTuple& rhs) 
            {
                using thrust::get;
                if (get<0>(lhs)== get<2>(lhs) && get<0>(lhs) != toExclude) 
                    return get<1>(lhs) < get<1>(rhs);
                else
                    return true ;
            }

};
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, never tested or compiled, use at own risk]

To set the value prior to passing the functor to a thrust algorithm, create and instance of the functor and pass it to the thrust call, for example:

```
forSecondMax op(10);
thrust::remove_if(A.begin(), A.end(), op);
```

which would set the data member `toExclude` to a value of 10 in a new instance of the class, and use the instance in the stream compaction call.