# Function object not working properly

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, thrust

I have defined the following function object:

```
struct Predicate1
{
   __device__ bool operator () 
       (const DereferencedIteratorTuple& lhs, const DereferencedIteratorTuple& rhs) 
  {
    using thrust::get;
    //if you do <=, returns last occurence of largest element. < returns first
    if (get<0>(lhs)== get<2>(lhs) && get<0>(lhs)!= 3) return get<1>(lhs) < get<1>(rhs); 
    else
    return true ;
  }
};
```

where the DereferencedIteratorTuple is as follows:

```
typedef thrust::tuple<int, float,int> DereferencedIteratorTuple;
```

Moreover, i call it as follows:

```
result =  thrust::max_element(iter_begin, iter_end, Predicate1());
```

But the result is the tuple (3,.99,4). I am confused why this is the result because the condition `get<0>(lhs)== get<2>(lhs)` does not hold in the `if` for this tuple. Thus, the operator returns true for every comparison of this tuple. However, `thrust::max_element`is defined as follows :

> "This version compares objects using a function object comp.
>   Specifically, this version of max_element returns the first iterator i
>   in [first, last) such that, for every iterator j in [first, last),
>   comp(*i, *j) is false."

Thus, there is no way this should be chosen as for this tuple, operator never returns false. Please let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: If someone asked this to be closed, please explain why

Comment: Is it possible that there are no values that meet the criteria ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate helps algorithm to determine which element to prefer. If predicate returns `true` the algorithm prefers `rhs` over `lhs`. If it return `false` the algorithm prefers `lhs` over `rhs`. In the case when predicate always returns `true` the algorithm will select last element in the array. This is true for both stl and thrust algorithms.

I guess, that your result never occured as `lhs` during comparison process and every time it was not filtered since rhs's second value was smaller than 0.99.

If you want to filter such values you'd better rewrite your predicate.